# Changing url/ip when asynctask is running repeatedly

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have call the GetXMLTask from my service and it will repeatedly call every 1 seconds to get data from the IP address (MyIP).

MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (GlobalFunctions.isInternetAvailable(MyService.this)
                || GlobalFunctions.isWifi(MyService.this)) {

            MyTimerTask myTask = new MyTimerTask();
            Timer myTimer = new Timer();

            myTimer.schedule(myTask, 1000, 1000);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "No Internet Connection", 1000).show();
        }

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
            task.execute(new String[] { MyIP });
        }    
    }
}
```

asynctask is use in the GetXMLTask.java.

```
public class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        try {
            String output = null;
            for (String url : urls) {
                output = getOutputFromUrl(url);
            }
            return output;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and now when the apps is running, i have change the ip address, but the "urls" still showing the previous ip address (see the data from eclipse debug mode) and it the "urls" will be updated after quite a long time.

May i know what should i do so that urls in the asynctask can directly take newest ip address without long delay.

thank you so much

**Updated 24/4/2014:**

I have make changes for the doinBackground code, but the data received from the IP address is still not the updated data.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    try {
        String output = null;
        String[] newurl = {GlobalVariables.Global_URL + "/status.xml"};
        for (String url : newurl) {
            output = getOutputFromUrl(url);
        }

        return output;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any idea? Thank You

**Updated 25/4/2014:**

I have debug the code and notice that when IP address is changed, the asynctask seem like freeze for quite a long time. I have put the break point in the doinbackground, and it doesn't go in.
Any idea? thank you

Answer (score 0):

The for loop in doInBackground is processing urls sequentially. You may need to check for change in ip inside for loop and if ip has changed do the needful (for example updating urls accordingly).

Comment: Sir. i have make changes on doinbackground code. but i'm still need to wait for around 1 to 2 minute to get the updated data from the new ip address. thanks